# Plasticity between excitatory and inhibitory neurons?

Tags: neuroscience, synapses, neuroplasticity

All that I've learned about synaptic plasticity only concern the synapses between excitatory neurons. For example, all pyramidal neurons (excitatory) in the cortex have plastic synapses between them, but as far as I know there are no plastic synapses between pyramidal neurons and their inhibitory interneurons.

So I am curious, are there any plastic synapses between inhibitory and excitatory neurons?

Answer (score 1):

Various forms of plasticity has been reported for inhibitory-excitatory synapses as well. See below figure from [Woodlin et al. 2003].
[image]

- Holmgren CD, Zilberter Y (2001) Coincident spiking activity induces long-term changes in inhibition of neocortical pyramidal cells. J Neurosci 21: 8270–7
- Woodin MA, Ganguly K, Poo MM (2003) [Coincident pre- and postsynaptic activity modifies GABAergic synapses by postsynaptic changes in Cl- transporter activity](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0896627303005075). Neuron 39: 807–20